# How to use log4net in a DLL project?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a project in which I want to use `log4net` for logging. When I'm testing my project using a console app program, it does not log anything unless I write the `log4net` section in the `app.config` of the test project. How do i fix this ?

This is my configuration in my `app.config` file in the DLL:

```xml
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="MyLogFile.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{ABSOLUTE} [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value ="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref ="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: config files that belong to a dll are not read, at least not automatically. The process that loads your dll, has control over which configuration will be used.

Comment: ok , but if in my assignment I need to submit only the DLL file and they will run it as they see fit , how do I make sure that the logger will work ?

Comment: well, if you're unsure if those using your dll are able or wiling to configure it correctly you might not have chosen the best option. Check if the current answer works for you, otherwise seek an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

From `log4net` documentation page: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html (*Configuration Files* section)

> The only way to configure an application using the System.Configuration APIs is to call the log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() method or the log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(ILoggerRepository) method.

Make sure you are initializing log4net on your console app.